# reopen/leave closed vote counting?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

I was just looking at a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28091265/jquery-dynamic-buttons-html) in the reopen queue and I noticed that on the question's page it is marked as having 1 reopen vote. I voted to keep it closed, but the 1-reopen-vote is still displayed on the question page.

So, my question is about how these votes are counted. Certainly, if other users think my vote was wrong they're entitled to vote to open it, and if enough users do this then the question should be reopened. But, how many 'stay closed' votes are needed before the closure becomes certain? That is, do the 'stay closed' votes count for anything, or are they completely ignored?

Comment: I hope there is no finite number of "keep closed" votes that would outweigh a significantly greater number of "reopen" votes.

Comment: So would I. But, if say 5 people vote to keep this closed, and there has been no edits to the question, perhaps it should be removed from further voting? My concern is that not all votes are carefully considered and it may take a small number of inattentive people to reopen something that maybe many people have decided is not a good match for SO. But really, I want to know if it's worth my effort to vote to remain closed, when I could just skip the question and have the same results with less risk of falling fowl of an unfair test question.

Comment: The "not carefully considered" vote issue acts in both directions. I've seen questions closed due to what superficially looked like a duplicate, but did not in fact answer the new question.

Comment: A certain number of "keep closed"-votes, just like successfully opening, will complete the revew-task. The number of "keep closed"-votes needed is based on how many people voted to re-open.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three votes to leave it closed will end the review task and mark it as completed (note that the number of reopen votes does not affect this number) - so it won't be shown to any further reviewers and won't collect any more reopen votes through review.

That outcome does **not** clear existing reopen votes (initially), nor does it prevent other users from continuing to vote to reopen the question outside of review. All it does is start the aging process for the existing reopen votes, meaning that after four days if no new reopen votes have come in, they'll start aging away one day at a time until they are all gone.

Comment: Thanks for that. Is this stuff written down in some nook of SE that I haven't found yet?

Comment: Most of the FAQs are on MSE: [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)