# Attempt to quell seemingly overly-enthusiastic close votes

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues

**Update**

I consider this issue closed.

I did not anticipate that so many people would be so adamantly against allowing re-open votes to take place simultaneously with close votes taking place.

As for those asking me for links (evidence), you have a good point.  Although I have experienced this over the years, I did not keep a list, and I am unwilling to invest the time to search for them.  I accept that my experience in this matter is rare, and perhaps even unique.

---

I see way too many good questions that are voted to be closed<sup>1</sup>.  And the current SO UI doesn't even explain why a question has been voted to be closed until *after* it is already closed.

I would like the ability to counter close votes *before* the question is closed in two ways:

1. Be able to view the rationale for the close vote, and the identity of the close voter prior to the question being closed.  That way I can decide if I agree or disagree with the rationale for closing.  Perhaps I'll add my vote to close or not.
2. Be able to vote to re-open *proactively* prior to the question being closed, and supply the rationale for why the question should remain open.

I am writing this because too many of the questions I see closed seem to be closed simply because the close-voters don't know the answer to the question, and subsequently interpret the question as unanswerable.  By the time someone knowledgeable comes around who could offer a beneficial answer, the question is already closed (sometimes within less than an hour of the question being asked).

Another possible solution would be to have a "minimal open time" for a question of say 24h, prior to closing so that more people would have a chance to weigh in or supply answers prior to closing.

It is not a level playing field for the reopen-voters when the only recourse they have is the comment section on an already-closed vote.

I submit that there are far more bad answers, than bad questions.  So the benefit of the doubt should lean towards the questioner.

---

<sup>1</sup>I am *not* referring to questions I have asked.  I am referring to questions others have asked, and I would like the opportunity to answer.

Comment: *"Be able to view the rationale for the close vote"* On non-mobile, you can  see this if you open the close dialog, and see the blue counter for which reasons have been voted for.

Comment: Fair point.  I was afraid to do that because that link said "close vote" and I didn't want to add my vote to that.

Comment: A minimal open time isn't going to work unless there is a way for the community to eliminate garbage questions bypassing that limit.

Comment: I definitely don't want to see a cure that is worse than the disease.  And UI on a network such as SO is not my area of expertise.  I may not have outlined the correct solution in my question.  My only goal is to open the discussion and give potential re-open voters a fighting chance.

Comment: If you have a question you think needs reopening, you can chat about it in [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) (that room doesn't just review for closing, reopen requests are also welcome).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara:  Thanks.  I did not know about that list.  It doesn't seem like a UI that is as friendly to reopening/keeping-open a specific question as the current UI is to closing one.

Comment: Suggestion 1a (show breakdown of close votes) is already implemented, as mentioned by Alexander O'Mara. I'm not sure if suggestion 1b (show identity of close voters) would help reasoning about the close vote rationales. Suggestion 2 is rather interesting -- it sounds like a better implementation for [*Directly vote to not close a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298520/2751851). For what it's worth, my own suggestion in this problem space is [*One-time notification about questioned close votes*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336788/2751851).

Comment: "I submit that there are far more bad answers, than bad questions. So the benefit of the doubt should lean towards the questioner." I suspect that *massively* depends on which tags you frequent. In the Java and C# tags, I'd say that bad questions significantly outnumber bad answers.

Comment: 'I see way too many good questions that are voted to be closed' - guess what comes next..... yes, you guessed it - link some.

Comment: 'I am writing this because too many of the questions I see closed seem to be closed simply because the close-voters don't know the answer to the question, and subsequently interpret the question as unanswerable.' - sorry, don't believe you without evidence.  Please list some.

Comment: 'I submit that there are far more bad answers, than bad questions.' - not even close.

Comment: 'Another possible solution would be to have a "minimal open time" for a question of say 24h, prior to closing' - that would be the end of SO as anything but an open sewer.

Comment: I know you've already moved on, but you [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348472/attempt-to-quell-seemingly-overly-enthusiastic-close-votes#comment468893_348472) you didn't dare clicking on "close", because you thought it might vote immediately, which made me wonder – and in fact, it seems you've not cast a *single* close vote, ever (and only 5 down votes, at that). Do you really think there is nothing close-worthy, or do you frequent incredibly high-quality tags?

Comment: I have a high tolerance for beginners.  Some of the best questions I've ever seen in my life (years before SO even existed) have come from beginners.  I have even standardized C++ library features that were inspired by a beginner's "naive" question.  If I think a question is not a great question, I don't upvote it.  If I down vote it for any reason, I leave a comment as to why.  When I come across a question that is so bad that I think it should be closed, 100% of the time it has already been closed by others.  Some of that time, in my opinion the question should not have been closed.

Comment: Some of that time, the closed question has even been upvoted multiple times, and there exists upvoted answers for the question, and yet it was still closed (and not a duplicate).  No I don't have a link to such an example.  But I recall it happening.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: We have rules for whether a question should and should not be closed. We do not close beginner questions because they're from beginners. We close them when they do not meet our quality standards, whether they are from beginners or not. These standards are (mostly) objective, and they don't necessarily reflect the *idea* behind the question. Someone can ask what might be an insightful question, but however insightful it is, it may be too opinionated for SO. Or too broad. Or whatever.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  I respect the rules.  I sometimes see them abused.  Here is the question that inspired me to make this post.  It was not closed.  But it does have a single close vote, and that close vote was the proverbial straw / camel's back for me: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43647211/576911

Comment: @HowardHinnant: But... that's an example of the system *working*. The reason we require 5 close votes to close a question is precisely to *prevent* a single person from using close votes to close questions that shouldn't be closed. Someone either misread the question or has an improper interpretation of the rules. But since the question was never actually closed, I don't see how that can be the straw that broke the camel's back when it's not even a *straw*.

Comment: I don't see how me asking for a feature that allows an easy counter-keep-open vote (prior to 4 more people piling on) can be so upsetting to you.  Don't worry.  I'm not getting that feature.  You can rest easy now.

Comment: I didn't mean to pile on, in case you referred to me – I was genuinely curious if you never see anything you think should be closed, because in my SO experience (for example browsing the "Help and Improvement" queue), sometimes the majority of questions I come across are unsalvageable garbage. I commend you for your patience and efforts to improve this site as a whole.

Comment: 'Although I have experienced this over the years, I did not keep a list, and I am unwilling to invest the time to search for them.' - this, I'm afraid, is typical of the response to 'provide examples' :(  All sorts of claims have been made on meta re. 'unjustified' downvoting.  Supposedly, some downvote becasue they don't understand the question.  Some downvote becasue they are sociopathic.  Some downvote at random.  Some downvote out of a malicious sense of elitism etc etc.  EVERY time that such claims are made and someone asks for examples, they are not forthcoming.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit:  Oh, good grief.  Here's what SO says I've voted to re-open: http://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant?tab=votes&sort=reopen  For some reason I don't understand, if you actually visit those questions, there are no revotes counted.

Comment: @BenjaminW.:  No, I wasn't referring to you at all.  You're inquiry was most respectful.  By "pile on" I was referring to the tendency of a single close vote to attract other close votes, whether or not the initial close vote was well considered or not.

Comment: Ah, okay :) As to why you can't see your reopen votes any longer: they "age away", see for example [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284285/3266847).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I see, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

> Be able to view the rationale for the close vote, and the identity of the close voter prior to the question being closed. That way I can decide if I agree or disagree with the rationale for closing. Perhaps I'll add my vote to close or not.

You can already see that. Well, the useful part of that. Click the "close" button, and you'll see all of the close votes that have been made. You *won't* see who made them, because really that serves no purpose towards determining whether the question ought to be closed for that reason.

> Be able to vote to re-open proactively prior to the question being closed, and supply the rationale for why the question should remain open.

There's an entire menu for voting to close. There is no such menu for voting to reopen, since the reason for doing so is always the same: the question is fine for the site.

As for preemptive reopening, such that it takes a net 5 close votes to close a question... no. It's hard enough to close crap questions as it is; we shouldn't make it harder.

The #1 most effective way to keep a question from being closed is to *fix it*. If you genuinely believe that the question doesn't need to be fixed, look at the close vote reasons and clarify (either in a comment or a question edit) why the question shouldn't be closed.

> It is not a level playing field for the reopen-voters when the only recourse they have is the comment section on an already-closed vote.

I think that's dismissive, since it takes 5 votes to close a question. So the deck is clearly stacked in the direction of "open" rather than "closed". There are tons of crap questions in low traffic tags that don't get closed, simply because 5 people with close voting powers don't deign to do so.

Also, the number of improperly closed questions is pretty small next to the number of *properly* closed questions. I am not aware of a particular rash of improperly closed questions. Yes, it happens, but I don't feel that it is often enough to warrant a site change.

Now, what *might* be OK is if your preemptive reopen vote doesn't actually take effect until the question actually gets closed. So it still only takes 5 votes to close, but if 5 preemptive reopen votes are made, then the close is instantly undone. But this should also mean that a closed question should be able to be given preemptive reclose votes.

I also have to take issue with:

> I am referring to questions others have asked, and I would like the opportunity to answer.

We don't close questions just because someone doesn't want the opportunity to answer them. We close questions because they *shouldn't be answered*, either in their current form or at all.

There have been many questions I've voted to close which I have found intriguing. But the quality of this site is fundamentally based on the quality of questions. And question quality is not based on whether you like the question; it's about whether it makes for a good question for the site.

Comment: *We don't close questions just because someone doesn't want the opportunity to answer them. We close questions because they shouldn't be answered, either in their current form or at all* you haven't seen enough of the C++ tag. The problem @HowardHinnant poses is real, I saw many times people voting to close questions for "religious" reasons (one of the worse is when areas where the language is weak are exposed, and people react with close votes).

Comment: *I saw many times people voting to close questions for "religious" reasons* @MatteoItalia - I would think it would be better to flag for moderator attention in that case. I don't suppose you have the link to one of those questions?

Comment: @MatteoItalia: "*one of the worse is when areas where the language is weak are exposed, and people react with close votes*" That sounds very much like people closing an opinionated question asking about why some aspect of the language is designed that way. That's not "religious"; that's a valid close reason. Can you give examples of what you're talking about?

Comment: 'I saw many times......' examples please.

Answer (score 6):

> Another possible solution would be to have a "minimal open time" for a question of say 24h, prior to closing so that more people would have a chance to weigh in or supply answers prior to closing.

You're going to trap users with unsalvageable questions. Answers (or one up voted answer) make questions un-deleteable and unfortunately many users choose to post answers for typos, recommendation requests, and other questions that can't be fixed. This would actually make it harder for users who make mistakes to avoid question bans.

This also means a lot more questions that aren't useful are going to get stuck on the site simply because the larger about of votes and effort it takes to get rid of them aren't available.

Comment: "This also means a lot more questions that aren't useful are going to get stuck on the site simply because the larger about of votes and effort it takes to get rid of them aren't available" -- For one, it would largely nullify dupe hammers.